# Does Jmeter re transmit requests, in case of packet droping event?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm trying to test a web application using Jmeter. In a typical web application system, there exist packet drops, specially when the queues are full [1]. In case of such packet droping event, does Jemter re transmit the request again, or is that considered as a failed request (marked as error) ?

[1] Wang, Q., Lai, C. A., Kanemasa, Y., Zhang, S., & Pu, C. (2017). A Study of Long-Tail Latency in n-Tier Systems: RPC vs. Asynchronous Invocations. Proceedings - International Conference on Distributed Computing Systems, (1), 207–217. https://doi.org/10.1109/ICDCS.2017.32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it doesn’t in order ti detect such issues that can be due to configuration issues.

But this behaviour is adjustable using 2 properties:

- httpclient4.retrycount

> Number of retries to attempt. Retry will be done on Idempotent Http Methods by default. If you want to retry for all methods, see property httpclient4.request_sent_retry_enabled
>   Defaults to: 0

- httpclient4.request_sent_retry_enabled

  > Set this property to true if it's OK to retry requests that have been sent. This mean that both Idempotent and non Idempotent requests will be retried. This should usually be false, but it can be useful when testing against some Load Balancers like Amazon ELB.
  >   Defaults to: false

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient4